# How to filter query in graphQL one to many relation?

Tags: graphql, pimcore

I have two tables `tire` and `brand`. They have one-to-many relationship.
So when I try following query

```
  getTireListing (sortBy: "title") {

    edges {
      node {
        title
        description1
        description2

        brand  {
          ... on object_brand {
            brandName
          }
        }

      }
    }
    totalCount
  }
```

I am getting following result.

```
{
  "data": {
    "getTireListing": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "title": "Continental-ContieCocontact 5",
            "description1": "<p>test</p>\n",
            "description2": "<p>test 2</p>\n",
            "brand": {
              "brandName": "Continental"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "title": "PremiumContact TM 6",
            "description1": "<p>test</p>\n",
            "description2": "<p>test</p>\n",
            "brand": {
              "brandName": "Continental"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "title": "Tire name",
            "description1": "<p>fgafd</p>\n",
            "description2": "<p>asfasdf</p>\n",
            "brand": {
              "brandName": "Abc Brand"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "totalCount": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Now I need to filter tire with brand name, so I tried

```
getTireListing (
 sortBy: "title",
 filter: "{\"brand\" :  {\"brandName\": \"Continental\" } }"
)
```

but I am getting error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'brandName' in 'where clause'`

I am a newbie to GraphQL. Can anybody please help?

Comment: explore possible `filter` properties in playground or input type definitions

Comment: @xadm I have tried since yesterday. I am kinda lost now. That's why seeking help.

Comment: just explore 'docs' in `/graphiql` playground, you should find available queries and possible arguments (input types) for each type/object/table

Comment: can you edit your question and add the code to the resolver function of `getTireListing` ?

Comment: @Tal Z Those are my full query. I don't know what else you asking

Comment: Do you have access to the backend? Because it seems the issue might be with the code that talks to the db. Do you have the code to the function that receives your graphql query?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this with the Pimcore data hub extension?

Comment: @Blackbam Yes. I am using that .

Comment: @nas This extension is still in alpha. As there are still not many people using this I guess you should create a ticket at: https://github.com/pimcore/data-hub

Comment: @Blackbam I have created a ticket. https://github.com/pimcore/data-hub/issues/224

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following code :

```
filter : "{\"brandName\": {\"$like\" :\"%Continental%\"}}"
```